# How do I become an Ubuntu Partner so I can build devices?

Tags: intel

How do I become a partner so I can build Ubuntu devices on Intel Atom/Sofia?

Comment: Perhaps start here: http://partners.ubuntu.com/contact-us ?

Comment: How did I get here? I filled this out on the canonical site..

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, a community-driven Q&A site where we answer *software questions* about the Ubuntu Operating System.

Though there are some Canonical employees here, most of us are not, so you'd be better off redirecting your question [directly to Canonical](http://www.canonical.com/services/contact-us), the company behind Ubuntu as your question is off-topic here...

#### ;-)

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: I agree, though I think this should be a comment since it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I deleted it after the Q was closed but apparently, someone undeleted it...

Comment: Yeah, and I can't see anything in the edit section, so it must have been a mod...  Not going to delete it again!  **:/**